# rowIndex when creating a table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild

I have the following function to append rows and cells to an empty `table`:

```
        function createTable(size) {
            var table = document.getElementById("gameTable");
            for (var i=0; i<size; i++) {
                var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                for (var j=0; j<size; j++) {
                    var td = document.createElement("td");
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                }
                table.appendChild(tr);
                tr.rowIndex = i;
            }

        }
```

So far so good.

My problem is that later, when I tried to reach specific cells inside the table:

```
var x = target.parentNode.rowIndex;
var y = target.cellIndex; 

table.rows[x].cells[y].innerHTML = 'blah'
```

`target` is the specific `TD` that was clicked.

the `rows[x]` index is always `-1`. Every time I try the line above I get an error: "cannot read property 'cells' of undefined"
 I even tried manually setting the rowIndex of each Row to what it should be (inside the function), but to no avail.

The cellIndex comes out fine, but the rowIndex is -1 and each and every one of the newly created table rows.

What can I do to correct this?

Comment: Where is your code when you try to reach the table?

Comment: You really should be appending to a tbody and not the table element.

Comment: I've edited to make it clearer. a table element already exists, I just add TRs and TDs.

Comment: it works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/2PCCd/  show us how you set `x` and `y` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by appending the `<tr>` elements into a `<tbody>`.

```
        function createTable(size) {
            var table = document.getElementById("gameTable");
            var tb = document.createElement("tbody");
            for (var i=0; i<size; i++) {
                var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                for (var j=0; j<size; j++) {
                    var td = document.createElement("td");
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                }
                tb.appendChild(tr);
            }
            table.appendChild(tb);
        }
```

Comment: the table creation works fine in Chrome without a tbody.  The problem must be in how he's _accessing_ the `.rows[]` property.